# Applying gradient to Material UI's theme background

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to make the default background color of the MuiTheme a gradient, I have the following code:

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
    background: {
      default: "linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%)",
    },
  },
})
```

However I noticed that material-ui sets it as `background-color` and gradients are not allowed there.
Is there a way to bypass this and have it become `background` instead?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default theme background is actually applied by the `CssBaseline` component. You can override the global default styles it use using the `overrides` property in your `theme` object.

```
export const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
         body: {
           background: 'linear-gradient(45deg, #fe6b8b 30%, #ff8e53 90%)',
           backgroundRepeat: "no-repeat",
           backgroundAttachment: "fixed",
        },
      },
    },
  },
  palette: {
    type: "dark",
  },
})
```

[CssBaseline](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/)

[Global CSS](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css)

Comment: doesn't work: You have to add !important to background value

Answer (score 8):

If you are using MUI version "^5.8.7",
then below should work

```js
import {
  createTheme
} from '@mui/material/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: #FAACA8,
          backgroundImage: `linear-gradient(19deg, #FAACA8 0%, #DDD6F3 100%)`,
        },
      },
    },
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@latest/umd/material-ui.development.js"></script>
```

Comment: The accepted answer does not work for me. But this solution work well in my app