# Linear-gradient background to Material UI Theme

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

> Hi, I used an external json file to set the theme.

> Now I wanted to use a linear-gradient as background but probably not being a real palette >but a background image doesn't set it correctly.

> Do you have any solution?

```
"palette": {
"mode": "light",
  "background": {
   "default": "linear-gradient(to right, #cc2b5e , #753a88)"
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Strongly recommend you on checking this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72888543/10161096

create a component inside your theme and put your linear-gradient inside backgroundImage. This solution works well to me